# Change Notes plasmoid background

Tags: kde, kde4, plasma

Is there any way to change the notes plasmoid background? 
I tried looking for the plasmoid in `/usr/share/kde4/apps/plasma/plasmoids/` and `~/.kde/share/apps/plasma/plasmoids/` to change it myself(if it's not binary of some uneditable sort) but could not find the widget at all.

Also if there's another notes plasmoid which is more customizeable, i'd appreciate it if you told me. Right now I'm going through the kde-look.org site plasmoids section page by page, but haven't found a hit so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Plasma**

The plasma is using the svg images to theme the plasma desktop and the widgets. More of the plasma themes: https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma/Theme

The notes plasma widget / plasmoid background image is the notes.svg(z).

From the deb packages the themes are installed to the  /usr/share/kde4/apps/desktoptheme/[THEME_NAME].

If a user adds a theme from the KDE system settings > Workspace Appearance > Desktop Theme > Get New Themes. The theme will be installed to the ~/.kde/share/apps/desktoptheme/[THEME_NAME].

The default plasma theme notes background is: /usr/share/kde4/apps/desktoptheme/default/widgets/notes.svgz

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but after opening the image in an editor, I realized that this is not the theme for my notes widget. I'm sure that I've seen that exact background on a note widget, but can't remember when and where. My notes widget looks like this, can you be dear and take look at it for me, thanks a lot :) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22496113/snapshot3.png

Comment: I guess it was this same notes. But why isn't it showing the themes from notes.svgz anymore??? As a matter of fact, I can't change font, font size, font style, etc anymore either!

Comment: What themes do you have ?

Comment: Did you see that picture, snapshot3.png? The themes are all like that but come in various colors, about 6 or 7.

Comment: I figured it out. The notes theme depends on the workspace theme. And the notes.svgz is used with the Air theme. Thanks a lot for pointing out the notes.svgz file.